# difference of nagios-plugins and nagios-plugins-all rpm packages

Tags: rpm

I am a bit confused as to the purpose of those two rpm packages installed from epel repository. As far as i can see , nagios-plugins package just installs a few scripts:

```
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/negate
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/urlize
/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/utils.sh
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/CODING
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/COPYING
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/ChangeLog
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/FAQ
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/LEGAL
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/README
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/README.Fedora
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/REQUIREMENTS
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/SUPPORT
/usr/share/doc/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/THANKS
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/nagios-plugins.mo
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/nagios-plugins.mo
```

And the package nagios-plugins-all contains the actual plugins:

```
Installing for dependencies:
 nagios-plugins                         x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel               251 k
 nagios-plugins-breeze                  x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                18 k
 nagios-plugins-by_ssh                  x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                44 k
 nagios-plugins-cluster                 x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                37 k
 nagios-plugins-dhcp                    x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                44 k
 nagios-plugins-dig                     x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                44 k
 nagios-plugins-disk                    x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                45 k
 nagios-plugins-disk_smb                x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                21 k
 nagios-plugins-dns                     x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                45 k
 nagios-plugins-dummy                   x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                33 k
 nagios-plugins-file_age                x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                19 k
 nagios-plugins-flexlm                  x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                20 k
 nagios-plugins-fping                   x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                43 k
 nagios-plugins-game                    x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                39 k
 nagios-plugins-hpjd                    x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                42 k
 nagios-plugins-http                    x86_64               2.2.1-4git.el7                 epel                60 k
 nagios-plugins-icmp                    x86_64
```

What is the purpose of nagios-plugins package and utils.sh ?
Why two separate packages?

Answer (score 3):

Think of `nagios-plugins` like the foundation. There are a lot of `nagios-plugins-*`. the `all` package installs them all but you can hand pick certain ones.

Now the main `nagios-plugins` setups up the foundation like the dir structure and commonly used files like the ones you  have shown. If each of the `nagios-plugins-*` installed those files they would fight with each other and life wouldn't be fun.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply mike. How did you find the answer? Is it documented somewhere or is this out of experience. Also, what does the utils.sh is actually used for?

Comment: I just know how RPMS get packaged since I've been through the pain of doing it